# Does all SP, function must be recompiled, if new column added to the table

Tags: oracle

One question about ORACLE stored procedures and functions:
I added the new column to the table. This table involve in many stored procedures and functions without using a new column. Do I have to recompile function and procedures, which are using the table, even a new column is not involve in the query of those SP and function? Also do I have to update statistics and so on?

I understand, theoretical question, but anyway. 
Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage)? and why did you tag your question with `oracle`?

Answer (score 0):

1- if source objects are changed, stored procedures and functions which depend of them must be compile again.

2- If you want to learn which sp or function depends your table, you can try something like;

```
select * from USER_SOURCE where text like '%your_table_name%';
select * from DBA_SOURCE where text like '%your_table_name%';
select * from ALL_SOURCE where text like '%your_table_name%';
```

3- You must not collect statics but it will be useful aggregate and update histograms for performance.

Comment: By depends you mean that they use new column from that table or just use the table name with other columns, except new?

Comment: just use the table name with other columns, except new?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you change. You can look at [the `all_dependencies` view (or the `user_` or `dba_` equivalents)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F9EA7DFB-5471-4B07-BDEF-FDE5DF57D1F4.htm#REFRN20053) to see what may be affected, and [the `user_objects` view](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-AA6DEF8B-F04F-482A-8440-DBCB18F6C976.htm#REFRN20146) to see if something has been made invalid for any reason:

```
create table t42 (col1 varchar2(10));
insert into t42 (col1) values ('val1');

create procedure p42 as
  l_col1 t42.col1%type;
begin
  select col1 into l_col1 from t42;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_col1);
end p42;
/

column object_name format a12

select object_type, object_name, status
from user_objects
where object_name in ('T42', 'P42');

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME  STATUS 
------------------- ------------ -------
PROCEDURE           P42          VALID  
TABLE               T42          VALID  

select type, name, dependency_type
from user_dependencies
where referenced_type = 'TABLE' and referenced_name = 'T42';

TYPE               NAME                           DEPE
------------------ ------------------------------ ----
PROCEDURE          P42                            HARD
```

Adding a column doesn't invalidate the procedure in this case:

```
alter table t42 add (col2 varchar2(10));

select object_type, object_name, status
from user_objects
where object_name in ('T42', 'P42');

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME  STATUS 
------------------- ------------ -------
PROCEDURE           P42          VALID  
TABLE               T42          VALID
```

Modifying the column used by the procedure does though:

```
alter table t42 modify (col1 varchar2(20));

select object_type, object_name, status
from user_objects
where object_name in ('T42', 'P42');

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME  STATUS 
------------------- ------------ -------
PROCEDURE           P42          INVALID
TABLE               T42          VALID
```

But you don't have to explicitly recompile the procedure; you can if you want to, but Oracle will automatically try to recompile an invalid object when it is referenced:

```
exec p42;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

select object_type, object_name, status
from user_objects
where object_name in ('T42', 'P42');

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME  STATUS 
------------------- ------------ -------
PROCEDURE           P42          VALID  
TABLE               T42          VALID
```

You can also use [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_plscope.htm#ADFNS022) to get more information and details about dependencies too.